# Java Mailbox for Stored Email Addresses

Tags: java

Hopefully somebody can help. I have successfully created a Java message class to model a standard email message but I am unsure how to proceed with a Mailbox class necessary to store the emails from the Message class.

**Message Class**

```
public class Message {    
    private String recipient;
    private String sender;
    private String message;
    private String body;

    public Message(String recipient, String sender){
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String toString(){           
        message = "From: " + recipient + "\nTo: " + sender; 
        return message;
    }

    public String append(){          
        body = "\nThis is the body content of your message";  
        return body;
    }
}
```

**Mailbox Class**

```
public class Mailbox {     
    public void addMessage(Message m)
    {

    }

    public Message getMessage(int i)
    {

    }

    public void removeMessage(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where will `MailBox` save the messages?

Comment: Hi @RaviH it is just a tester program. A MailboxTester class will be used to demonstrate the functionality of the Mailbox class. I am just unsure as to how to begin building the add, get, remove methods of Mailbox class. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Vector / ArrayList can hold items / objects. So you can go to your mailbox class and create an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
```

Then you can add:

```
messages.add(new Message(...));
```

and delete:

```
messages.delete();
```

your messages.